# Choosing between updating current state or emitting new state in Flutter BLoC/Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, clean-architecture, state-management

I've been exploring different approaches to manage state in Flutter using BLoC and Cubit, and I've come across two common patterns. I'd like to understand the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.

1. Updating Current State with copyWith:

In my SearchPageCubit, I have a copyWith method that allows me to update the current state by creating a new instance with modified properties. Here's a snippet:

```
// [Snippet from SearchPageCubit.dart]
class SearchPageState extends Equatable {
  // ... (existing code)

  SearchPageState copyWith({
    Status? status,
    String? searchText,
    List<SearchAutoCompleteModel>? searchList,
  }) {
    return SearchPageState(
      status: status ?? this.status,
      searchText: searchText ?? this.searchText,
      searchList: searchList ?? this.searchList,
    );
  }
}
```

2. Emitting New State:

On the other hand, in my SearchResultsBloc, I emit new states for different scenarios, such as loading, success, or failure. Here's a snippet:

```
// [Snippet from SearchResultsBloc.dart]
class SearchResultsSuccessState extends SearchResultsState {
  final List<SearchResultModel> results;

  const SearchResultsSuccessState({
    required this.results,
  });
}

class SearchResultsFailureState extends SearchResultsState {
  final String message;

  const SearchResultsFailureState({
    required this.message,
  });
}
```

I'd like to hear the community's insights on which approach is generally preferred and in what scenarios. Are there specific use cases where one approach is more suitable than the other? Any performance considerations or best practices that I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance for your guidance!

I've implemented both approaches in different parts of my Flutter application, and both seem to work as expected. However, I'm keen on understanding the community's experiences and best practices to make an informed decision.

For the **"Updating Current State with `copyWith`"** approach:

- I've used the `copyWith` method to update the current state when specific changes occur.
- I expected that this approach might lead to more concise code, as I'm modifying the existing state without emitting new instances.

For the **"Emitting New State"** approach:

- I've used distinct state classes for different scenarios, such as loading, success, or failure.
- I expected that this approach might provide more clarity in the code, especially when dealing with complex state transitions.

What I'm looking for:

1. Guidance on the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.
2. Recommendations on which approach is considered more idiomatic or in line with best practices.
3. Any performance considerations or potential pitfalls associated with either approach.

Any insights or examples from your experiences would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Updating Current State with `copyWith`:

**Advantages:**

1. Immutability and Clarity: Using copyWith ensures immutability, which
   can be beneficial for tracking state changes and avoiding unintended
   side effects. It also provides a clear and concise way to express
   state modifications.
2. Consistency: The use of a single state class with a copyWith method
   promotes consistency in how state modifications are handled
   throughout your application.
3. Flexibility: You have fine-grained control over which properties to
   update, allowing you to modify only the necessary parts of the state.

**Considerations:**

1. Boilerplate Code: Depending on the number of properties in your
   state, the copyWith method might generate a significant amount of
   boilerplate code.
2. Debugging: When debugging, it might be more challenging to trace
   state changes back to their origins, as the same state instance is
   being modified.

Emitting New State:

**Advantages:**

1. Clarity and Separation of Concerns: Different state classes for
   distinct scenarios (loading, success, failure) enhance code clarity
   and make it easier to understand the current application state.
2. Predictability: Each state class represents a specific state of the
   UI, making it easier to predict the application's behavior based on
   the emitted state.
3. Redux DevTools Compatibility: If you ever integrate with tools like
   Redux DevTools, emitting new states can provide better visibility
   into state changes and time-travel debugging.

**Considerations:**

1. Increased Number of Classes: Using distinct state classes might lead
   to a larger number of classes, especially if your application has
   many different states.
2. Potential for Redundancy: In some cases, you may find yourself
   repeating similar properties across different state classes, which
   could be perceived as redundant.

In general, Flutter is optimized for efficiently rebuilding the UI based on changes in the widget tree. The performance impact of either approach is likely minimal in most scenarios.

For more i suggest you to read https://bloclibrary.dev/